# How to disable load_ssh_configs in fabric (used as library) from user code?

Tags: python, paramiko, fabric

I'm using `fabric` as a library and want to avoid loading my local `~/.ssh/config` file (etc).

[Fabrics configuration docs](https://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/concepts/configuration.html#disabling-ssh-config) declare: "To do so, simply set the top level config option `load_ssh_configs` to `False`."

Unfortunately they do not say how to execute this simple act. I want to use code to change this default. I do not want to create more (config) files.

```python
# not like this
load_ssh_configs = False  # does not work in code; works from config file, I guess

# not like this either
import fabric
conf = fabric.Config()
conf.load_ssh_configs = False  # too late, conf.base_ssh_config already loaded

# hopeless
global_defs = fabric.Config.global_defaults()  # not a singleton, but a copy
global_defs.load_ssh_configs = False  # no effect

# this works, but needs parameter for every `fabric.Connection`
conf2 = fabric.Config(lazy=True)  # should be called e.g. `load_files`, not `lazy`
c = fabric.Connection('host1', config=conf2)  # finally skipped `.ssh/config`

# works as well, but even more complicated
import paramiko
ssh_conf = paramiko.config.SSHConfig()
conf3 = fabric.Config(ssh_config=ssh_conf)
c = fabric.Connection('host1', config=conf3)
```

Am I missing something? Is there no simple way of globally disabling `ssh_config`-loading from within my code?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: Create a `~/.fabric.yaml` with:

```yaml
load_ssh_configs: false
```

## Update

Without using a configuration file, you can disable reading ~/.ssh/config by creating a `fabric.Config()` object as such:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import paramiko
import fabric

config = fabric.Config(ssh_config=paramiko.SSHConfig())
conn = fabric.Connection(host="primary", config=config)
```

The config created this way, will not load the `~/.ssh/config` file. That config will be used by the connection object.